# custom border/polygon in ggplot

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, border, ggmap

I have a data table

```
dt_dt <- data.table(color=c(6.3, 6.8, 8.3, 8.4, 8.4, 7.5, 7.9, 7.3, 7.8, 5.2),
                 lat = c(47.78125, 47.78125, 47.78125, 47.78125, 
                         47.78125, 49.03125, 49.03125, 49.03125,
                         49.03125, 49.03125),
                 long = c(-121.21875, -121.28125, -121.34375, -121.40625, 
                          -121.46875, -122.46875, -122.53125, -122.59375, 
                          -122.65625, -122.71875),
                  fips = c(53061, 53061, 53061, 53061, 53061, 53073, 
                           53073, 53073, 53073, 53073)
                 )
```

I would like to plot borders around each group, given by the `cluster` column, so, there is a border/polygon around each cluster.

I can plot it with

```
states <- map_data("state")
states_cluster <- subset(states, region %in% c("washington"))
dt_dt %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = states_cluster, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               fill = "grey", color = "black") +
  geom_point(aes_string(x = "long", y = "lat",
                        color = "color"), 
                        alpha = 1,
                        size=.3) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "plasma", 
                        name = "storm", direction = -1,
                        limits = c(min, max),
                        breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 4))
```

However, I do not know how to plot the borders.
adding

```
 + geom_polygon(fill = "transparent", color = "red", size = 1, 
           data = dt_dt, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = fips))
```

at the end does not work. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I think we need more points in order to help you with this example. If I filter `dt_dt` for `fips == 53061`, the points all have latitude of 47.78125 and will restult in plotting a straight line rather than a polygon.